# gpiod_get_array() fails to get the gpio_desc[] that gpio_count() sees

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio

I am trying to `gpiod_export()` from the driver (pinctrl-single.c), some named user GPIOs declared in the device tree (DTS). I want them available in userspace to get or set from an application. I also expect they will be shown as "used" from `gpioinfo`. I can get the `gpiod_count()` and an associated name from the device tree using `of_property_read_string_index()`, but I fail to get descriptors using either `gpiod_get_array()` or `gpiod_get_index()`.

After getting the descriptors, I was planning to `gpiod_export()` the array of GPIOs and `gpiod_export_link()` associate a name with them.

Why is `gpiod_get_array()` failing in the sequence below to return the descriptors `gpio_count()` sees?

(Some error checking omitted for conciseness)

```c
int gpio_count, gpio_name_count;
struct gpio_descs *gpiodescs;
    
gpio_count = gpiod_count(pcs->dev, "my"); // RETURNS 3
gpio_name_count = of_property_count_strings(np, "my-gpio-names"); // RETURNS 3
    
// THE FOLLOWING FAILS TO RETURN THE DESCRIPTORS
gpiodescs = devm_gpiod_get_array(pcs->dev, "my", GPIOD_OUT_LOW); // returns IN_ERR
if (IS_ERR(gpiodescs))
    dev_warn(pcs->dev, "failed to get gpio array (%d)\n", gpiodescs);
```

In a loop, the following also fails to get the descriptor

```c
descp = devm_gpiod_get_index(pcs->dev, "my", i, GPIOD_OUT_LOW);
if (IS_ERR(descp))
    dev_warn(pcs->dev, "failed to get gpio desc\n");
```

the abbreviated DTS is

```dts
&am33xx_pinmux {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    my-gpios =  <&gpio2 4 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>,
            <&gpio2 3 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>,
            <&gpio2 0 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;

    my-gpio-names = "name1",
            "name2",
            "name3";
```

Comment: This is the last time I fix your Q. Next time will just vote -1.

Comment: Now to the Q. Try to add more information, like  what the exact error code you get and so on. And side not: avoid using OF APIs when they may be omited (`device_property_string_array_count()`).

Comment: please explain, "This is the last time I fix your Q" so that I can improve future questions.

Comment: Just click on edit history and look what I have done. Try to follow when asking a new question(s).